# VB.NET TryParse returns False although a valid date passed

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, parsing, date

I created a function in VB.NET that checks for valid dates. The function is below:

```
Public Shared Function IsDate(obj As [Object]) As Boolean
        Dim strDate As String = obj.ToString()
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

        If DateTime.TryParse(strDate, dt) AndAlso dt <> DateTime.MinValue AndAlso dt <> DateTime.MaxValue Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

I pass a value to that function that I think is a valid date. My test value is 49278 that should correspond to a date of 30th Nov 2034.

My function however tells this is NOT a valid date. I cannot get why.

[image]

What is happening here?

Comment: That's clearly a `Double`, why do you expect that it can be converted to `Date` via `DateTime.Parse`? Use `DateTime.FromOaDate`.

Comment: My scenario is here I am reading data from an Excel file and whenever user enters a date I will get it as this kind of double value that I want to validate. I check your suggestion...

Comment: Whoever teached you that a string representation of a number could be parsed as a date didn't make a good work. TryParse wants a string that can be interpreted as a date I.E. "04/12/2014". And this could not be enough if you consider different locales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is an "OLE Automation Date" as used by Excel etc.

`DateTime.Parse` requires a string representation of a date like `12th Nov 2034` or `3/5/14` and is parsed by default using the culture information of the thread context it is running under.

In your case I think you should just check if the value is an Double first and then use `DateTime.FromOADate` if it is:

```
Public Shared Function IsDate(obj As Object) As Boolean
    Dim dt As DateTime
    Dim d As Double
    Dim strDate As String = obj.ToString()

    If Double.TryParse(strDate, d) Then
        dt = DateTime.FromOADate(d)
        'parsed OA date
    ElseIf DateTime.TryParse(strDate, dt) Then
        'parsed string representation of date
    Else
        dt = DateTime.MinValue
    End If
    Return (Not dt = DateTime.MinValue AndAlso Not dt = DateTime.MaxValue)
End Function
```

Note: There is no need for the square brackets round the Object declaration.

Maybe to improve this your should have an overloaded method with one accepting a double and one a string, then you don't have the overhead of boxing and unboxing value types when calling it using a double value

```
Public Shared Function IsDate(d As Double) As Boolean
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Try
        dt = DateTime.FromOADate(d)
        Return (Not dt = DateTime.MinValue AndAlso Not dt = DateTime.MaxValue)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Public Shared Function IsDate(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim dt As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(s, dt) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Even better - create an extension method of the above, then you can do something like this `49278R.IsDate`

Answer (score 1):

That's a `Double`, it can't be parsed to `Date` via `DateTime.Parse`, use [`DateTime.FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Public Shared Function IsDate(obj As Object) As Boolean
    If obj Is Nothing Then Return False

    Dim dt As DateTime
    If TypeOf obj Is DateTime Then
        dt = DirectCast(obj, DateTime)
    Else
        Dim strDate As String = obj.ToString()
        If Not DateTime.TryParse(strDate, dt) Then
            Dim oaVal As Double
            If Double.TryParse(strDate, oaVal) Then
                Try
                    dt = DateTime.FromOADate(oaVal)
                Catch ex As ArgumentException
                    Return False
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return dt <> DateTime.MinValue AndAlso dt <> DateTime.MaxValue
End Function
```

Comment: Returns TRUE when passing empty string "" into the function

Comment: @user2143213: note that i've edited my answer to add the type check but even the old version returned `False`. If you pass `"` it cannot be parsed to double which means that it returns false because `dt` is `Date.MinValue`.